# Should I use implicit annotation for AngularJS dependency injection?

Tags: developer, angular

I am learning AngularJS and have read that it supports [three different ways](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#dependency-annotation) to specify dependencies.

Their docs say that [inline array notation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#inline-array-annotation) "is the preferred way to annotate application components". Further, they "recommend avoiding" [implicit annotation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#implicit-annotation) because it cannot safely pass through a JavaScript minifier. Ok.

But most of the AngularJS code in CiviCRM appears to be using implicit annotation ([example](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/ad16ac09d007265ca54a83b83c65961d42eeb702/ang/crmAttachment.js#L7-L7)).

Thus, I am wondering:

- Was "implicit annotation" a conscious design choice for some reason? (e.g. Maybe CiviCRM has some 3rd-party tool like [ng-annotate](https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate) in place to add inline array notation before minification?)
- Or perhaps: is the implicit syntax I'm seeing just incidental? In which case I would guess that I should *avoid* replicating this syntax when writing *new* code (for the sake of compatibility with potential future minification strategies).